# Gmail addon Inline installation

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-addons

I am looking for a way to do inline installation of gmail addon.

I am aware about the in-line addition of chrome extensions which is no more supported.

For a Drive addon aleast I see its possible as its implemented here :

https://welcome.aodocs.com/dms/.

Kindly correct me if this is something different.
However, I do not see any documentation anywhere indicating how aodocs has achieved this.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: I tried the link. It did an installation of aodocs chrome extension and not a gmail add-on. Are you trying do to a similar approach to install addon?

Comment: @hari: The links does domain-wide install of a drive addon. Yes I wanted to check if similar flow can be used for a gmail addon.